# Run-time error '3144': Syntax Error in Update Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm running into some issues with my update statement, the Add statement seems to work but I keep getting a syntax error in update. I am new to SQL and VBA so a lot of this probably looks like sphagetti code. If anyone can Identify what I did wrong that would be much appreciated. If there is a better way to do it, please let me know.

```vb
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Dim mbrName As String
Dim mbrOffice As String
Dim mbrRank As String
Dim mbrOpType As String
Dim mbrRLA As String
Dim mbrMQT As String
Dim mbrPos As String
Dim sqlAdd As String
Dim sqlUpdate As String
If Me.opgMngRoster.Value = 1 Then

    '-Set Middle Name to NMI if blank
    If IsNull(Me.txtMidInit.Value) Then
        Me.txtMidInit.Value = "NMI"
    End If

    '-Create Member's Name string in all uppercase
    mbrName = UCase(Me.txtLastName.Value & ", " & Me.txtFirstName.Value & " " & Me.txtMidInit)

    '-Member's Office
    mbrOffice = Me.cbxOffice.Value

    '-Member's Rank
    mbrRank = Me.cbxRank.Value

    '-Member's Operator Type
    mbrOpType = Me.cbxOpType

    '-Member's RLA
    mbrRLA = Me.cbxRLA.Value

    '-Member's MQT Program
    mbrMQT = Me.cbxMQT.Value

    '-Member's MQT Position
    mbrPos = Me.cbxTngPos.Value


    'ADD MEMBER TO ROSTER
    sqlAdd = "INSERT INTO [ROSTER] (MEMBER, OFFICE, RANK, OPTYPE, RLA, [MQT-PROGRAM], [MQT-POSITION]) VALUES ('" & mbrName & "', '" & mbrOffice & "', '" & mbrRank & "', '" & mbrOpType & "', '" & mbrRLA & "', '" & mbrMQT & "', '" & mbrPos & "');"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlAdd)

    '-Confirmation Msg
    MsgBox ("Added: " & mbrName)

Else

    '-Set Middle Name to NMI if blank
    If IsNull(Me.txtMidInit.Value) Then
        Me.txtMidInit.Value = "NMI"
    End If

    '-Create Member's Name string in all uppercase
    mbrName = UCase(Me.txtLastName.Value & ", " & Me.txtFirstName.Value & " " & Me.txtMidInit)

    '-Member's Office
    mbrOffice = Me.cbxOffice.Value

    '-Member's Rank
    mbrRank = Me.cbxRank.Value

    '-Member's Operator Type
    mbrOpType = Me.cbxOpType

    '-Member's RLA
    mbrRLA = Me.cbxRLA.Value

    '-Member's MQT Program
    mbrMQT = Me.cbxMQT.Value

    '-Member's MQT Position
    mbrPos = Me.cbxTngPos.Value

    'Update Member Data
    sqlUpdate = "UPDATE [ROSTER] (MEMBER, OFFICE, RANK, OPTYPE, RLA, [MQT-PROGRAM], [MQT-POSITION]) VALUES ('" & mbrName & "', '" & mbrOffice & "', '" & mbrRank & "', '" & mbrOpType & "', '" & mbrRLA & "', '" & mbrMQT & "', '" & mbrPos & "');"
    Debug.Print sqlUpdate

    DoCmd.RunSQL sqlUpdate

    MsgBox ("Updated: " & mbrName)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Check update statement https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp you are using something like insert sintaxis

Comment: Lookup documentation about using parameterized queries, instead of manually concatenating strings like this. FWIW that is terrible practice leaving a wide-open SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza what does w3schools know of Access-SQL?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Update sintaxis ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza don't you think actual [**MS-Access documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845036.aspx) would be a much better place to link to, versus some clunky website listing "SQL Syntax" without even specifying what dialect it's for?

Comment: I'm guessing that this line is throwing the error: DoCmd.RunSQL sqlUpdate. Can you verify what the output is of this line into the immediate window:  Debug.Print sqlUpdate

Comment: @GregViers OP is using an `UPDATE` statement structured like a weird-looking `INSERT` command. `UPDATE [table] (field_list) VALUES (values_list)` should be `UPDATE [table] SET [field1]=[value1], [field2]=[value2], ... WHERE [condition]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several general coding and specific MS Access issues with your setup:

1. First, no need to repeat your VBA variable assignments for both `If` and `Else` blocks. Use DRY-er code (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself).
2. Also, since you do not apply further calculations, there is no need to assign the majority of form textbox and combobox values to separate string variables. Use control values directly in query.
3. Use parameterization (an industry best practice) which is not only for MS Access but anywhere you use dynamic SQL in an application layer (VBA, Python, PHP, Java, etc.) for any database (Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, SQLite, etc.). You avoid injection and any messy quote enclosure and data concatenation.

   While languages have different ways to bind values to parameters, one way in MS Access is to use [querydef parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) as demonstrated below.
4. Save your queries as stored objects with `PARAMETERS` clause (only compliant in MS Access SQL dialect). This helps abstract code from data.
5. Finally, properly use the update query syntax: `UPDATE <table> SET <field>=<value> ...`

**Insert SQL Query** *(with parameterization, save once as stored query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS MEMBER_Param TEXT, OFFICE_Param TEXT, RANK_Param TEXT, OPTYPE_Param TEXT, 
           RLA_Param TEXT, MQT_PROGRAM_Param TEXT, MQT_POSITION_Param TXT;
INSERT INTO [ROSTER] (MEMBER, OFFICE, RANK, OPTYPE, RLA, [MQT-PROGRAM], [MQT-POSITION]) 
VALUES (MEMBER_Param, OFFICE_Param, RANK_Param, OPTYPE_Param, 
        RLA_Param, MQT_PROGRAM_Param, MQT_POSITION_Param);
```

**Update SQL Query** *(with parameterization, save once as stored query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS MEMBER_Param TEXT, OFFICE_Param TEXT, RANK_Param TEXT, OPTYPE_Param TEXT, 
           RLA_Param TEXT, MQT_PROGRAM_Param TEXT, MQT_POSITION_Param TXT;
UPDATE [ROSTER]
SET MEMBER = MEMBER_Param, OFFICE = OFFICE_Param, RANK = RANK_Param, 
    OPTYPE = OPTYPE_Param, RLA = RLA_Param, [MQT-PROGRAM] =  MQT_PROGRAM_Param, 
    [MQT-POSITION] = MQT_POSITION_Param;
```

**VBA** *(no SQL shown)*

```vb
Dim mbrName As String, myquery As String, mymsg As String
Dim qdef As QueryDef

'-Set Middle Name to NMI if blank
If IsNull(Me.txtMidInit.Value) Then
    Me.txtMidInit.Value = "NMI"
End If

'-Create Member's Name string in all uppercase
mbrName = UCase(Me.txtLastName.Value & ", " & Me.txtFirstName.Value & " " & Me.txtMidInit)

If Me.opgMngRoster.Value = 1 Then   
    myquery = "myRosterInsertQuery"
    mymsg = "Added: " & mbrName
Else
    myquery = "myRosterUpdateQuery"
    mymsg = "Updated: " & mbrName
End If

' ASSIGN TO STORED QUERY
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(myquery)

' BIND PARAMS
qdef!MEMBER_Param = mbrName  
qdef!OFFICE_Param = Me.cbxOffice.Value
qdef!RANK_Param = Me.cbxRank.Value
qdef!OPTYPE_Param = Me.cbxOpType
qdef!RLA_Param = Me.cbxRLA.Value
qdef!MQT_PROGRAM_Param = Me.cbxMQT.Value
qdef!MQT_POSITION_Param = Me.cbxTngPos.Value

qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

'-Confirmation Msg
MsgBox mymsg, vbInformation

Set qdef = Nothing
```